# Alternative to return Option<Box<[Box<[JsValue]>]>> from Rust fn to Wasm

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to return `std::boxed::Box<[std::boxed::Box<[wasm_bindgen::JsValue]>]>`
in my Rust code to Wasm but getting this error.

I understand the trait is not implemented, but is there a workaround to it?

### Raw Error

#[wasm_bindgen]

| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `wasm_bindgen::convert::traits::OptionIntoWasmAbi` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<[std::boxed::Box<[wasm_bindgen::JsValue]>]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer, I managed to return `Option<js_sys::Array>` to solve this. I know it is not exactly the same what I was looking for but it works for me.